# support for google-apis node client for google pay pass (event tickets)

Tags: google-api

I would like to use google api -node js client (googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to register event ticket class, I would like to make a post call to https://www.googleapis.com/walletobjects/v1/eventTicketClass .

Is this supported by the node client? Has any one integrated with this end point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Issued rest calls from node.js there was a set up issue with service account, thats why calls were not going thru. google api node js client has no support for event register api since its fairly new.  Just google auth library , got the JWT token and then used it in authorization header and registered the event and updated it.

Comment: Would you please add a sample of how you used it with nodejs?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit further ? I am also trying to implement the pass rest api with node and I am always getting permission denied